# datagrid after filtering c# ( filtering in show is right but in click event is non changed)

Tags: c#, filter, datagrid

I have a `datagrid` (not `datagridview`) in my project that store my SQLite database columns on it. That works perfectly and shows everything right. And when I filter `datagrid` by a `textbox`, that filters correctly. But after filtering, when I click on a row (`rowindex`), `datagrid` shows before filtering information in the filtered rows. Showing of filtering is right but when I click the filtered rows for retrieving information in some `textbox`, that retrieves non-filtered information. Filtering is working but when I click on rows that seems nothing happened. What I have to do?

This `datagrid` click event:

```
private void Grid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    i = Convert.ToInt32(DT.Rows[Grid.CurrentRowIndex]["id"]);

    btnDel.Enabled = true;
    btnEdit.Enabled = true;
    txtDesc.Text = DT.Rows[Grid.CurrentRowIndex]["letternum"].ToString();
    txtDesc2.Text = DT.Rows[Grid.CurrentRowIndex]["name"].ToString();
    txtDesc11.Text = DT.Rows[Grid.CurrentRowIndex]["docimage"].ToString();
    label10.Text = DT.Rows[Grid.CurrentRowIndex]["docimage"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: i think if i can set rowindex as a column like id , that work right but i dont know how do this

Comment: So, you stored the id inside i but never really used it. Can't tell with the limited information.